# iTermがフルスクリーン + 二重に起動されるようになった

Tags: macos, iterm

MacでiTermを使っているのですが、以下の不具合が発生しました。
・起動時に二重に起動する
・どちらもフルスクリーンで起動する

以下のことを試しましたが解決しませんでした。
・command + returnでフルスクリーンが解除できない
・カーソルでウィンドウを縮めようにも、画面端にてポインタが変わらず縮小できない
・再起動

直前に行ったこと
・プロフィールを新規作成し、それをデフォルトにしていた（今は削除して初期のものを使用）

フルスクリーンの状態を解除できないと作業が遅滞するので困っています。どなたかご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 関係あるかはわかりませんが、
Preference から Settings for New Windows の欄が選択できませんでした

Comment: 治りました！！！　exitと打って消したら治りました……なんで？　その後、Setting for New WindowsでStyleをTop of Screenにしたらまた同じような現象が……。フルスクリーンになりません。消して普通にやろうと思います。

Comment: 回答を探した場合、[自分の投稿を自分で回答できます](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。そうすることで、将来同じ問題と戦っている人がすぐ回答を見つけることができます！

Answer (score 1):

windowをexitと打って消しました。それだけで治りました。

Comment: 回答（コメント欄に書いている、解決した手順）を書いてください。

Comment: windowをexitと打って消しました。それだけで治りました。